# Does Rep Count for anything anymore?

Tags: discussion

**Is this for real? W.T.F.** 
I'd like to point out that vandalism was attributed to a real User, totally unacceptable.

[image]

**Now its telling me "This post does not meet our quality standards".**

[image]

This is just insulting.

Comment: FWIW, you can click through to the question or the scape-goat user with these tests.  It's a good way to verify that the review is just a test instead of an actual issue.

Comment: The quality standards issue was when creating this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue has been discussed on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170683/stop-using-real-accounts-in-suggested-edit-audits/171562#171562). Clearly something is still going on. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 4):

Not entirely sure what you're asking here, but... The various quality checks do take rep into account - beyond a certain point, it's assumed you know what you're doing in certain areas (code formatting, for instance).

The basic writing-style checks apply to everyone though. Complete sentences, punctuation, and enough text to reasonably explain a problem are universally important.

[As World Engineer notes](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5769/does-rep-count-for-anything-anymore/5770#5770), suggested edit audits are temporarily attributed to a random recent editor - they don't actually appear in his activity though, nor does approval or rejection have any effect on him. Once you've completed the audit, the [Community user](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) will be displayed instead.